# Fill ViewFlipper in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, viewflipper

I am trying to load images into my FlipView using AsyncTask but Im not sure how to continue.
I need to use AsyncTask because the application is force closing since I have 20 images to load from the drawables.

```
private class asyncImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        int i;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (i=0;i<imageID.length;i++){
                image = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
                image.setId(i);
                image.setImageResource(imageID[i]);
                image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                FlipV.addView(image);
            }
            return null;
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

        image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        for(int x=0;x<imageID.length;x++){
            FlipV.addView(???); //How to add images into FlipView?
        }
    }

}
```

Im stuck in adding the images to the FlipView. Any help?

Comment: if you load pictures from the resources, you do not need to use asyntstask

Comment: but the app is crashing if i have more than 10 images or so. kind of a memory problem.

Comment: what in logcat? or you getting ANR error?

Comment: im getting an ANR. not sure if its a memory problem or a problem with my execution of the AsyncTask. i cant check it since i've already solved my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned from my comment I've already solved my problem by using an imageview array instead ang loading the images in the doInBackground and adding the imageviews in the viewflipper in the postExecute. I've also added a progress dialog to show a loading time instead of a blank screen in my app. Thanks to everyone that replied.

```
private class asyncImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        int i;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (i=0;i<imageID.length;i++){
                image[i] = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
                image[i].setImageResource(imageID[i]);
                image[i].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                image[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            for (int x=0;x<imageID.length;x++){
            FlipV.addView(image[x]);
            }
            count = 1;
            progDialog.dismiss();
            txItem.setText(Integer.toString(count) + "/" + (imageID.length));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant add instructions to doInBackground method which affect event/UI thread. Instead you should use, publishProgress() method to notify event thread, and in onProgressUpdate() add view to flipview.

Comment: could you provide a sample for me? since i am getting confused for using loop to fill the ViewFlipper while using asynctask at the same time.